# Error in installing pyopt on windows 10 32 bit

Tags: python

I was trying to install PyOpt on windows 10 32 bit and encountered the following error.

`error: Command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include /TcpyOpt\pyNSGA2\source\nsga2.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\pyOpt\pyNSGA2\source\nsga2.obj" failed with exit status 2`

Any hint is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy can be a real pain to install. Personally I prefer to use anaconda for all highly compiled installations. They distribute binary python distributions.

I recommend miniconda as an alternative package manager to pip for scientific packages.

http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. I downloaded the miniconda but I realized that I have to reinstall all the python packages including numpy. My intention was to install pyOpt. Is there any other way to install PyOpt?Thank you.